# Updating the source geodatabase for select layers in ArcGIS Pro (multiple geodatabases used in one map)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, feature-class, data-source

I have a map that uses shapefiles from several geodatabases. I need to re-source several layers from one specific geodatabase to another. They are the exact same geodatabase; Geodatabase X was copied from Folder X to Folder Y.

I am looking for simple code that essentially asks ArcGIS Pro to "search for any shapefile currently be sourced by Geodatabase X in Folder X and source it instead from Geodatabase X in Folder Y". I have used the following code but it was not successful. Any ideas?

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r'C:\Projects\YosemiteNP\Yosemite.aprx')
aprx.updateConnectionProperties(None, r'C:\Projects\YosemiteNP\New_Data\Yosemite.gdb')
aprx.saveACopy(r"C:\Projects\YosemiteNP\YosemiteNew.aprx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Geodatabases don't hold shapefiles, so I'll assume you mean layers.

If you need to know [what layers are in a file GDB](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm):

```
source_fgdb = r'C:\Projects\YosemiteNP\New_Data\Yosemite.gdb'
fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(source_fgdb)
```

This creates an array of names of the feature classes in the FGDB. You can set it using a Python array literal (like `['Trails', 'Ranger_Stations']`). You can also modify the list.

Once you're happy with your list, [copy each](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm):

```
out_path = r"C:\Projects\YosemiteNP\Somewhere_Else\Yosemite.gdb"

for fc in fc_list:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(
        in_features=os.path.join(source_fgdb, fc),
        out_path=out_path,
        out_name=fc
    )
```

This assumes your target FGDB already exists. Otherwise use [`CreateFeatureClass`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-class.htm) before the loop.

If you are using shapefiles instead of FGDBs as the output, this will work just as well. Simply provide a directory for `out_path` and the shapefile name in `out_name`.

Comment: I think when you say layers in your first two paragraphs you mean feature classes.